# form.is_valid() is false when it shouldn't be

Tags: django-forms

So i'm new in Django and i'm trying some tutorials. This code is exact same as the one in tutorial but it does not work form me.

- `views.py`

  ```
  from .forms import BlogPostForm


  def blog_post_create_view(request):

      form = BlogPostForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid():
          print(form.cleaned_data)
      else:
          print(form.slug, form.title, form.content)
      template_name = "form.html"
      context = {"form": None}
      return render(request, template_name, context)
  ```
- `forms.py`

  ```
  from django import forms


  class BlogPostForm(forms.Form):
      title = forms.CharField()
      slug = forms.SlugField()
      content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
  ```
- `form.html`

  ```
  {% extends "base.html" %}

  {% block content %}

  {% if title %}
      <h1> {{ title }}</h1>
  {% endif %}

  <form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">SEND</button>
  </form>

  {%endblock%}
  ```

So when I run this, code the `is_valid()` functions returns `False` and I get :

> `AttributeError: 'BlogPostForm' object has no attribute 'slug'`

Comment: That might be because the slug you sent is empty. Try to set `forms.SlugField(blank=True)` then..

Comment: It looks like it your suggestion solved my problem, thank you.